# Extract a Specific data from Notepad and display in an another Notepad in c#

Tags: c#, notepad

Specific data I mean reading from one Keyword to another keyword from a textFile and displaying that data in a notepad on toolStripMenuItem Click.

The below code is for just displaying whole data of Text file, but I want specific content Only.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\someFile.txt");
```

Comment: A hint from me: use substract method.

Comment: why -1 I don't understand, is this question looks unclear?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried like this.

if (File.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + "\comments_from_SSRD1.txt"))
                    File.Delete(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + "\file1.txt");

```
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        bool endFlag = false;
        bool startFlag = false;
        sw = File.AppendText(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\file1.txt");
        foreach (string lineOf in errorReportContent)
        {


            if (lineOf.Contains("Report Of Conditionals Mismatch"))
            {
                startFlag = true;
            }
            if (lineOf.Contains("End Of Conditionals Mismatch Report"))
            {
                endFlag = true;
            }
            if (startFlag == true && endFlag != true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(lineOf);
            }





        }
        sw.Close();
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\file1.txt");
```